# Using underscore.js to increment a value based on number of times item seen in array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am trying to learn JS better.

I have the below code which I am trying to put into underscore.js but am failing.

I'm hoping you can point out where I'm going wrong.

I'm trying to take a loop that I know works and then use underscores capabilites to refine it. The top test shows the loops, the second test is my attempt to do the same with underscore.js. I'm failing miserably!

Thanks

```
 products = [
       { name: "Sonoma", ingredients: ["artichoke", "sundried tomatoes", "mushrooms"], containsNuts: false },
       { name: "Pizza Primavera", ingredients: ["roma", "sundried tomatoes", "goats cheese", "rosemary"], containsNuts: false },
       { name: "South Of The Border", ingredients: ["black beans", "jalapenos", "mushrooms"], containsNuts: false },
       { name: "Blue Moon", ingredients: ["blue cheese", "garlic", "walnuts"], containsNuts: true },
       { name: "Taste Of Athens", ingredients: ["spinach", "kalamata olives", "sesame seeds"], containsNuts: true }
    ];


it("should count the ingredient occurrence (imperative)", function () {
    var ingredientCount = { "{ingredient name}": 0 };

    for (i = 0; i < products.length; i+=1) {
        for (j = 0; j < products[i].ingredients.length; j+=1) {
            ingredientCount[products[i].ingredients[j]] = (ingredientCount[products[i].ingredients[j]] || 0) + 1;
        }
    }

    expect(ingredientCount['mushrooms']).toBe(2);
  });

  it("should count the ingredient occurrence (functional)", function () {
    var ingredientCount = { "{ingredient name}": 0 };


    var ffd = _(products).chain()
              .map(function(x){return x.ingredients;})
              .flatten()
              .reduce(function(memo,x){
                if (x===memo) 
                  {
                    return ingredientCount[memo] = ingredientCount[memo]+1;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    return ingredientCount[memo] = 0;
                  }

                  })
              .value();

        /* chain() together map(), flatten() and reduce() */

    expect(ingredientCount['mushrooms']).toBe(2);
  });
```

Comment: So um... whats your question exactly?

Comment: I don't have time to go over this right this moment but as a side note, `map(function(x){return x.ingredients;})` is the same as `pluck('ingredients')`

Comment: this comes from Javascript Koans https://github.com/mrdavidlaing/javascript-koans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reduce is not very functional. Have a look at its [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce)! The "memo", also know as "accumulator", is the value returned from the previous iteration - that should be your `ingredientCount` map.

```
var ingredientCount = _.chain(products)
  .pluck("ingredients") // don't use map for that
  .flatten()
  .reduce(function (memo, item) {
       memo[item] = (memo[item] || 0)+1;
       /* alternative:
       if (item in memo)
           memo[item]++;
       else
           memo[item] = 1;
       */
       return memo; // to be used in the next iteration!
  }, {/*"{ingredient name}": 0*/})
  .value();
```

Notice that `memo === ingredientCount`!

Comment: use `_(products).chain()`... 
or you'll get 
`TypeError: Object function (a){return new j(a)} has no method 'chain'`

Comment: @DavidWest: That seems to have changed with version 1.2.4, have a look at the [current docs](http://underscorejs.org/#chaining)

Comment: Thanks, Bergi. The Koan runner for this was using underscore version 1.1.6.

Comment: so memo is the returned object that we are adding item keys to? Wrapping my head around this... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use simpler to understand code, though it is not functional:

```
it("should count the ingredient occurrence (functional)", function () {

  var ingredientCount = { "{ingredient name}": 0 };

  var dummy = _(products).chain()
     .pluck("ingredients")
     .flatten()
     .each(function(x) { ingredientCount[x] = (ingredientCount[x] || 0) + 1; })
     .value();

  expect(ingredientCount['mushrooms']).toBe(2);
});
```